# how to create spatial buffers in flutter using flutter_map

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

How can one create a Polygon buffer, let's say 20 m around a specific point?

I am using the flutter_map package. Is there anyone who's got any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: add the code you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

So there's this package called dart_jts [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_jts) which is a port of the Java Topology Suite, which can do exactly this. The issue I have is how to specify the distance in metres or kilometres.

```
import 'package:dart_jts/dart_jts.dart' show GeometryFactory,Coordinate,Polygon,BufferOp;

final geometryFactory = GeometryFactory.defaultPrecision();

final point = geometryFactory.createPoint(
  Coordinate(
    longitude,
    latitude,
  ),
);
final distance = 0.0002;
// final buffer = point.buffer(distance);
final buffer = BufferOp.bufferOp3(point, distance, 6);
return buffer as Polygon;
```